# How to update only 1 of the rows if there are duplicates while using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a stored procedure that adds lunch hours based on `SUM(TotalTime)`. My dilemma is on the records that are duplicates. It adds lunch twice. See the screenshot below. I would like it to add in the lunch only once per day per employee based on the total hours worked. Here is what I have so far.

```
CREATE TABLE TimeCards 
(
    [Counter] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID nvarchar(50),
    Date DateTime,
    Lunch decimal(10,2),
    TotalTime decimal(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO TimeCards (EmployeeID, Date, Lunch, TotalTime)
VALUES ('1001', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 8) 
, ('136', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 4)
, ('136', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 4)
, ('418', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 5)
, ('418', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 5)
, ('511', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 5)
, ('511', '2021-02-04 00:00:00.000', Null, 6)

UPDATE TimeCards 
SET Lunch = CASE 
               WHEN SUMTotalTime BETWEEN 5.501 AND 11 THEN .5
               WHEN SUMTotalTime BETWEEN 11.01 AND 16 THEN 1
               WHEN SUMTotalTime >= 16.01 THEN 1.5
            END 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         tc.EmployeeID, Date, MAX(totaltime) AS totaltime,  
         SUM(TotalTime) AS SUMTotalTime 
     FROM 
         TimeCards tc
     GROUP BY 
         tc.EmployeeID, Date 
     HAVING 
         SUM(Totaltime) > 5.5) grouped 
 WHERE 
     TimeCards.totaltime = grouped.totaltime 
     AND TimeCards.Date = grouped.Date 
     AND TimeCards.EmployeeID = grouped.EmployeeID 
     AND grouped.SUMTotalTime > 5.5 
     AND Lunch IS NULL
```

[image: Current results of the query and Intended Results]

Comment: What do you want to happen if two matching rows ***already*** have one row with a NOT NULL value for Lunch, and the other row with a NULL value for Lunch?

Comment: There should only be one lunch on any given date. So if there is a not null value on one of the rows then that employee should be left alone

Comment: So, there would ***never*** be a case where there was one row with NULL Lunch, the stored procedure runs and calculates the Lunch value, then ***afterwards*** a new row is added and the first Lunch value needs to be recalculated?

Comment: I dont think that will ever be the case but that is a very good point. It should  always be looking for the SUM(totaltime) and recalculating if the SUMTotal increases. Thank you for thinking of that.

Comment: The 'correct' process then is to have a proper ETL pipeline.  Prior to a row being added to this table, any required calculations regarding `Lunch` are identified and processed.  As it stands, your stored procedure will have to recalculate the whole of history ***every single time***.  That's a resource leak.  *(Unless you have a mechanism for identifying which rows have been added since the last run of the stored procedure.  But even then, you're applying a sticking plaster, rather than treating the underlying condition.)*

Comment: @MatBailie agreed. In this particular scenario nothing would ever be adjusted that is more that a week  or two old. I can add that into my final procedure. I just got stuck on this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like what you want is an updatable CTE:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TC.EmployeeID,
           TC.[Date], --If this is a date, why is it a datetime?
           TC.Lunch,
           TC.TotalTime,
           SUM(TC.TotalTime) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date) AS TotalHours,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date ORDER BY Counter DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TimeCards TC)
UPDATE CTE
SET Lunch = CASE WHEN TotalHours BETWEEN 5.501 AND 11 THEN .5
                 WHEN TotalHours BETWEEN 11.01 AND 16 THEN 1
                 WHEN TotalHours >= 16.01 THEN 1.5
            END 
WHERE TotalHours > 5.5
  AND Lunch IS NULL
  AND RN = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d25fa2f5d847e904e2d6156414be2941)

If someone could already have a lunch added, and it might not be the "last" row, you could check that the "Max Lunch" is `NULL` instead:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TC.EmployeeID,
           TC.[Date], --If this is a date, why is it a datetime?
           TC.Lunch,
           TC.TotalTime,
           SUM(TC.TotalTime) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date) AS TotalHours,
           MAX(Lunch) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date) AS MaxLunch,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date ORDER BY Counter DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TimeCards TC)
UPDATE CTE
SET Lunch = CASE WHEN TotalHours BETWEEN 5.501 AND 11 THEN .5
                 WHEN TotalHours BETWEEN 11.01 AND 16 THEN 1
                 WHEN TotalHours >= 16.01 THEN 1.5
            END 
WHERE TotalHours > 5.5
  AND MaxLunch IS NULL
  AND RN = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ad3d28f19b7e0c2c3191063f4541b21)

Comment: The Date column is listed as datetime because that is how it is listed in the database I am working with. I created this table for my question so it was easier to work with. I just wanted to keep it consistent.

Comment: Based on comments the question has changed subtly.  I would change the `ROW_NUMBER()`'s `ORDER BY` to ensure rows that already have a `NOT NULL` value in `Lunch` are the ones that are updated.

Comment: Seems like what the OP should really be checking is that the "MAX Lunch" is `NULL`, @MatBailie , with the subtle change/missing requirement.

Comment: The OP's response to my second comment is that recalculation is required, as a new record ***can*** be added for the same Employee/Date ***after*** this has been run.  :  `I dont think that will ever be the case but that is a very good point. It should always be looking for the SUM(totaltime) and recalculating if the SUMTotal increases. Thank you for thinking of that.`

Comment: That moves the goal posts in my opinion, @MatBailie ... Something the OP shouldn't really be doing after they've received answers. it might be better to check that people's lunches are correct in a separate process, if I am honest, or to amend it when a row is also amended.

Comment: They moved the goal posts after I interrogated their requirements.  One could argue that your answer should mention that as an assumption, as it was not stated either way in the OP ;)  *(I still agree with you though.)*

Comment: I apologize. Didnt mean to move the goal post. Just something I didnt think of. I felt like MatBailie had a good point. I think your first answer and second answer too would work for me in the scenario I was presented.  I started down the CTE path but kept getting an aggregate error. I didnt know I could do it the way your answer did it. I appreciate the work you put into it. Thank you @Larnu

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, as I think I irritated Larnu and he doesn't seem to want to accomodate you comments ;)

Just change the `ROW_NUMBER()` part of his answer, and make it so that it picks the "rows-to-be-updated" based on whether the Lunch value is NULL before checking the `counter` value...

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TC.EmployeeID,
           TC.[Date], --If this is a date, why is it a datetime?
           TC.Lunch,
           TC.TotalTime,
           SUM(TC.TotalTime)
             OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date
                  )
                    AS TotalHours,
           ROW_NUMBER()
             OVER (PARTITION BY TC.EmployeeID, TC.Date
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN Lunch IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Counter DESC
                  )
                    AS RN
    FROM dbo.TimeCards TC)
UPDATE CTE
SET Lunch = CASE WHEN TotalHours BETWEEN 5.501 AND 11 THEN .5
                 WHEN TotalHours BETWEEN 11.01 AND 16 THEN 1
                 WHEN TotalHours >= 16.01 THEN 1.5
            END 
WHERE TotalHours > 5.5
  AND RN = 1;
```

Also, I strongly recommend NOT using `BETWEEN` on continuous values such as decimals, dates, etc.  In your scenario `CASE` will match the first true condition, so you can just do this...

```
SET Lunch = CASE WHEN TotalHours > 16.0 THEN 1.5
                 WHEN TotalHours > 11.0 THEN 1
                 WHEN TotalHours >  5.5 THEN .5
```

Even if you do need ranges, I recommend this...

```
SET Lunch = CASE WHEN TotalHours >  5.5 AND TotalHours <= 11.0 THEN .5
                 WHEN TotalHours > 11.0 AND TotalHours <= 16.0 THEN 1
                 WHEN TotalHours > 16.0                        THEN 1.5
```

It's slightly longer, but more explicit and more robust.